# SuperMicro IPMI no longer accessible after update

Tags: bios, ipmi

Going to keep this short:

- Got a new server
- We decided to update IPMI for reasons. I know - it's stupid without good reasons.
- Waited for it to reboot. On reboot it no longer is assigned an IP Address from the DHCP router, and setting a static IP through the BIOS doesn't help at all.

This is the motherboard I have: 
http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/QPI/5500/X8DTL-3F.cfm

We used the latest IPMI update download from the IPMI link on SuperMirco's webpage linked above.

I have installed an additional matching Xeon and 24GB of RAM as well as a 128GB SSD, but other than that have not done anything else with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it only inaccessible over network, or at all?

Did you tried ipmitool/ipmiutil?

If your BMC "alive", it should "answer" on commands from the host. And if so, you'll be able to reconfigure network and access lists.

If it is not:

1) try to poweroff machine, unplug power cable(s), press "power on" button (without the cable, just to clean capacitors).

Then enable and recheck.

2) as last resort you'll need to contact Supermicro's support and describe a situation.

Tell them that you faced ipmi-bugs under linux OS (it spammed logs with BMC bug messages "IPMI message handler: BMC returned incorrect response, expected netfn 2d cmd 0, got netfn 5 cmd 12" every second) and decided to upgrade IPMI firmware with firmware image linked from motherboard page, but BMC become inaccessible after firmware upgrade.

They should help you :)

Comment: I was just too quick to post because I didn't even remember to check hooking things into the dedicated ethernet port for it ;-;    sorry for wasting time.